# get the values of checked items with data-code value = '1' using .map in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

i have the input in which attribute `data-code` has different values and i need the ids of only those items whose `data-code` value is '1' and its checked by user:

Here is my code:

```
<input class="options_ids" type="checkbox" data-code='*ids_of_the_items*'>

var student_ids = $('input:checked.student_ids').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(",");
```

now in this jquery function i also need to check the attribute data-code value is '1' or null, if 1 then store it in var else exclude.

Comment: P.S: `options_ids` != `student_ids`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the attributes selector

```js
var student_ids = $('.options_ids[data-code="1"]:checked').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(student_ids)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="options_ids" type="checkbox" data-code='1' value="1" checked="checked">
<input class="options_ids" type="checkbox" data-code='5' value="2" checked="checked">
<input class="options_ids" type="checkbox" data-code='1' value="3" checked="checked">
<input class="options_ids" type="checkbox" data-code='6' value="4" checked="checked">
<input class="options_ids" type="checkbox" data-code='1' value="5" checked="checked">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var student_ids = $('.student_ids[data-code="1"]:checked').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get().join(",");

console.log(student_ids);
```

```html
<!-- use the right class -->
<input class="student_ids" type="checkbox" data-code='1' value="Dog" checked>
<input class="student_ids" type="checkbox" data-code='3' value="Hammer" checked>
<input class="student_ids" type="checkbox" data-code='1' value="Cat" checked>
<input class="student_ids" type="checkbox" data-code='14' value="Dance" checked>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```